# Why is \$V_o=-V_c\$ in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

Why is \$V_o=-V_c\$ in this circuit? Is it a derivation from Kirchhoff's voltage law?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Tz4D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hey , If I were you I would either go through some text or 10min video about virtual short. If you understand that , many such problems can be solved. The answers given below are perfect , but along with that  strengthen your basic in this concept since its important. And practice few problems in Sedra or any good text book  @JDoeDoe

Answer (score 4):

The key is to recognize that this circuit has negative feedback, so for an ideal op amp we can assume that \$V_- = V_+\$. Since \$V_+ = 0\,\text{V}\$, \$V_-\$ is effectively connected to ground (a **virtual ground**). Having made that assumption, KVL can be used to get the result.

Answer (score 4):

Reasoning: -

- Both the op-amp inputs are held at the same potential due to negative feedback.
- Therefore, because +Vin is at 0 volts, -Vin is forced to be 0 volts.
- You have placed plus and minus signs on the capacitor nodes and, the plus node is forced to be 0 volts (as per what I said above).
- Therefore, the op-amp output is intrinsically and indisputably the reverse polarity of the capacitor voltage.

> *Is it a derivation from Kirchhoff's voltage law*

No, it's an implication of how an op-amp uses negative feedback and, how the polarity symbols you have applied force \$V_{O}\$ to be the negative of \$V_{C}\$.

Answer (score 2):

That circuit is really an idealized integrator topology. So it's used for cases where you want to integrate. Not perform some KVL solution.

But given your question, the KVL is:

$$V_{_\text{OUT}}+V_{_\text{C}} +I_{R_1}\cdot R_1 - V_{_\text{IN}}= 0\:\text{V}$$

Since \$I_{R_1}=\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}-0\:\text{V}}{R_1}\$, we can re-write the above as:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{OUT}}+V_{_\text{C}} +\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}-0\:\text{V}}{R_1}\cdot R_1 - V_{_\text{IN}}&= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_\text{OUT}}+V_{_\text{C}} +\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1}\cdot R_1 - V_{_\text{IN}}&= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_\text{OUT}}+V_{_\text{C}} +V_{_\text{IN}} - V_{_\text{IN}}&= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_\text{OUT}}+V_{_\text{C}} &= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_\text{OUT}} &= -V_{_\text{C}}
\end{align*}$$

In more practical systems the integrating capacitor will have a resistor in parallel to it or else there will be a switch across the capacitor -- perhaps a COTO relay, for example, or else a semiconductor switch -- and the input source will be a photodiode instead of a voltage source. There would also be other switches included, as well. That might be what you'd see for low-frequency photodiode integrator. You can see the basics of such a system illustrated by the [Burr Brown ACF2101](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/acf2101.pdf?ts=1627194684529&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FACF2101), for example.

Comment: *However, to get there you do have to assume that \$V_{\text{IN}} = 0\text{V} \$ and that \$I_{R_1} = 0\text{A} \$.* I don't think this is true, @jonk . Because, in this special case the op-amp input voltages are \$V_+ = V_- = 0\text{V} \$ which causes \$V_{\text{IN}} = I_{R_1} \cdot R_1 \$ which can be seen by writing the KVL equation for that loop. This causes the term \$I_{R_1} \cdot R_1 - V_{\text{IN}}\$ to disappear in your first equation, regardless of what \$V_{\text{IN}}\$ is. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Carl Yes. Thanks for the kick in the head. I was focused on the static viewpoint of the author and attempting to over-simplify the situation. But poorly. I can do better and will. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, @jonk. +1 for a great edited answer.

Comment: @Carl Thanks so much for the privilege you offered in setting this right. It's terrible to have poor material floating about. Too much of it, already. It's my own shame I may have ignorantly added to that pile without your offer. Very much appreciated.